# Find a user's writable files and directories

Tags: files, permissions, find

How can I determine all files and folders that given user can write to? The user is `nobody`. Some script in bash or python, perhaps? I'm using Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
find / '(' -type f -o -type d ')' \
       '(' '(' -user  nobody -perm -u=w ')' -o \
           '(' -group nobody -perm -g=w ')' -o \
           '('               -perm -o=w ')' ')' -print
```

This will find all files and directories belonging to `nobody` that are writable by their owner, or that belong to the group `nobody` that are group writable, as well as all files or directories that are writable by anyone.

This would only take the primary group into account though.

Since generalizing this to take secondary groups (and ACLs etc.) into account would result in an even more unwieldy `find` expression, GNU `find` user could use

```
find / -type d -writable -print
```

This would report all directories writable by *the current* user. To use the same short syntax for finding directories writable by some other user, use `sudo -u username find ...`, i.e. change into that other user before running `find` (but see [an answer to a related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203646/116858) for caveats and better alternatives).