# Find files that a user can write, efficiently with minimal process creation

Tags: shell, files, permissions, users

I am root. I would like to know whether a non-root user has write access to some files - thousands of them. How to do it efficiently while avoiding process creation?

Comment: Please show us what you actually do!

Comment: Same kind of question as http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88591

Comment: Assuming you don't care about race conditions, why not just call [`access(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/access) with an appropriately set real-UID (e.g. via [`setresuid(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setresuid) or the portable equivalent)?  I mean, I'd be hard-pressed to do that from bash, but I'm sure Perl/Python can handle it.

Comment: @Kevin, shells' `[ -w` do generally use access(2) or equivalent. You also need to set the gids in addition to uid (as su or sudo do). bash doesn't have builtin support for that but zsh does.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - you can use [`chgrp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/chgrp.html) in any shell.

Comment: @mikeserv, `chgrp` doesn't change the gids of a _process_, my comment above was to complement Kevin's note that you should call `setresuid() + access()`. You also need `initgroups(3)`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - well of course not - it gets a new shell with a different gid. But another shell that can handle an altered gid is ksh - which comes with builtin support for altering both uid and gid - a superuser can start a ksh profile shell and drop privileges during a session and it will recognize that and do similar.

Comment: @mikeserv, not sure what you mean. zsh has support for changing euid, uid, gid (EUID, UID, GID... variables) and even set all of them based on information stored in the user database (as shown in my answer), but I can't see how you can do that with ksh93 nor what it has to do with `chgrp(1)`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - you have to build it with profile support - in which case not only can you do all of that, but `chgrp` is a builtin. Well, that and many other things. In fact, most of the stuff in the answers here become builtin when also built with the rest of the AST library.

Comment: Try building it, setting its binary set[ug]id and then chgrping or switching profiles to a different user [it comes with a builtin `login` as well] - then run id and see what you get. with ksh you don't even need sudo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

writable()
{
    local uid="$1"
    local gids="$2"
    local ids
    local perms

    ids=($( stat -L -c '%u %g %a' -- "$3" ))
    perms="0${ids[2]}"

    if [[ ${ids[0]} -eq $uid ]]; then
        return $(( ( perms & 0200 ) == 0 ))
    elif [[ $gids =~ (^|[[:space:]])"${ids[1]}"($|[[:space:]]) ]]; then
        return $(( ( perms & 020 ) == 0 ))
    else
        return $(( ( perms & 2 ) == 0 ))
    fi
}

user=foo
uid="$( id -u "$user" )"
gids="$( id -G "$user" )"

while IFS= read -r f; do
    writable "$uid" "$gids" "$f" && printf '%s writable\n' "$f"
done
```

The above runs a single external program for each file, namely `stat(1)`.

**Note:** This assumes `bash(1)`, and the Linux incarnation of `stat(1)`.

**Note 2:** Please read comments from Stéphane Chazelas below for past, present, future, and potential dangers and limitations of this approach.

Comment: That could say a file is writable even though the user has no access to the directory where it is.

Comment: That assumes file names don't contain newline character and file paths passed on stdin don't start with `-`. You could modify it to accept a NUL delimited list instead with `read -d ''`

Comment: Note that there's no such thing as a _Linux stat_. Linux is the kernel found in some GNU and non-GNU systems. While there are commands (like from `util-linux`) that are specifically written for Linux, the `stat` you're referring to is not, it's a GNU command which has been ported to most systems, not only Linux. Also note that you had a `stat` command on Linux long before GNU `stat` was written (the `stat` zsh builtin).

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas: _Note that there's no such thing as a Linux stat._ - I believe I wrote "the Linux incarnation of `stat(1)`".  I'm referring to a `stat(1)` that accepts the `-c <format>` syntax, as opposed to, say, BSD syntax `-f <format>`.  I also believe it was pretty clear I wasn't referring to `stat(2)`.  I'm sure a wiki page about the history of the common commands would be quite interesting though.

Comment: See [there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71595) for the various stats. Also, you could use GNU find's `-printf` (predates GNU stat by many years) to avoid having to run one stat per file.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas: _That could say a file is writable even though the user has no access to the directory where it is._ - True, and probably a reasonable limitation. _That assumes file names don't contain newline character_ - True, and probably a reasonable limitation. _and file paths passed on stdin don't start with -_ - Edited, thank you.

Comment: IMO, limititions are fine as long as they are clearly stated. Then the OP (or anyone coming here with the same or similar question) can decide if they are _reasonable_ for their specific use case. For instance, on a system with private home directories, that solution will report a lot of false positives (all the symlinks in all home directories for instance). It's not uncommon on file servers to have blanket strict _access_ restriction to one top-level directory and then relax all permissions for everything underneath...

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas: Note added.

Answer (score 18):

### TL;DR

```
find / ! -type l -print0 |
  sudo -u "$user" perl -Mfiletest=access -l -0ne 'print if -w'
```

You need to ask the system if the user has write permission. The only reliable way is to switch the effective uid, effective gid and supplementation gids to that of the user and use the `access(W_OK)` system call (even that has some limitations on some systems/configurations).

And bear in mind that not having write permission to a file does not necessarily guarantee that you can't modify the content of the file at that path.

### The longer story

Let's consider what it takes for instance for a $user to have write access to `/foo/file.txt` (assuming none of `/foo` and `/foo/file.txt` are symlinks)?

He needs:

1. *search* access to `/` (no need for `read`)
2. *search* access to `/foo` (no need for `read`)
3. *write* access to `/foo/file.txt`

You can see already that approaches (like [@lcd047's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203643) or [@apaul's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203635)) that check only the permission of `file.txt` won't work because they could say `file.txt` is writable even if the user doesn't have search permission to `/` or `/foo`.

And an approach like:

```
sudo -u "$user" find / -writeble
```

Won't work either because it won't report the files in directories the user doesn't have read access (as `find` running as `$user` can't list their content) even if he can write to them.

If we forget about ACLs, read-only file systems, FS flags (like immutable), other security measures (apparmor, SELinux, which can even distinguish between different types of writing) and only focus on traditional permission and ownership attributes, to get a given (search or write) permission, that's already quite complicated and hard to express with `find`.

You need:

- if the file is owned by you, you need that permission for the owner (or have uid 0)
- if the file is not owned by you, but the group is one of yours, then you need that permission for the group (or have uid 0).
- if it's not owned by you, and not in any of your groups, then the *other* permissions apply (unless your uid is 0).

In `find` syntax, here as an example with a user of uid 1 and gids 1 and 2, that would be:

```
find / -type d \
  \( \
    -user 1 \( -perm -u=x -o -prune \) -o \
    \( -group 1 -o -group 2 \) \( -perm -g=x -o -prune \) -o \
    -perm -o=x -o -prune \
  \) -o -type l -o \
    -user 1 \( ! -perm -u=w -o -print \) -o \
    \( -group 1 -o -group 2 \) \( ! -perm -g=w -o -print \) -o \
    ! -perm -o=w -o -print
```

That one *prunes* the directories that user doesn't have search right for and for other types of files (symlinks excluded as they're not relevant), checks for write access.

If you also want to consider write access to directories:

```
find / -type d \
  \( \
    -user 1 \( -perm -u=x -o -prune \) -o \
    \( -group 1 -o -group 2 \) \( -perm -g=x -o -prune \) -o \
    -perm -o=x -o -prune \
  \) ! -type d -o -type l -o \
    -user 1 \( ! -perm -u=w -o -print \) -o \
    \( -group 1 -o -group 2 \) \( ! -perm -g=w -o -print \) -o \
    ! -perm -o=w -o -print
```

Or for an arbitrary `$user` and its group membership retrieved from the user database:

```
groups=$(id -G "$user" | sed 's/ / -o -group /g'); IFS=" "
find / -type d \
  \( \
    -user "$user" \( -perm -u=x -o -prune \) -o \
    \( -group $groups \) \( -perm -g=x -o -prune \) -o \
    -perm -o=x -o -prune \
  \) ! -type d -o -type l -o \
    -user "$user" \( ! -perm -u=w -o -print \) -o \
    \( -group $groups \) \( ! -perm -g=w -o -print \) -o \
    ! -perm -o=w -o -print
```

(that's 3 processes in total: `id`, `sed` and `find`)

The best here would be to descend the tree as root and check the permissions as the user for each file.

```
 find / ! -type l -exec sudo -u "$user" sh -c '
   for file do
     [ -w "$file" ] && printf "%s\n" "$file"
   done' sh {} +
```

(that's one `find` process plus one `sudo` and `sh` process every few thousand files, `[` and `printf` are usually built in the shell).

Or with `perl`:

```
find / ! -type l -print0 |
  sudo -u "$user" perl -Mfiletest=access -l -0ne 'print if -w'
```

(3 processes in total: `find`, `sudo` and `perl`).

Or with `zsh`:

```
files=(/**/*(D^@))
USERNAME=$user
for f ($files) {
  [ -w $f ] && print -r -- $f
}
```

(0 process in total, but stores the whole file list in memory)

Those solutions rely on the `access(2)` system call. That is instead of reproducing the algorithm the system uses to check for access permission, we're asking the system to do that check with the same algorithm (which takes into account permissions, ACLs, immutable flags, read-only file systems...) it would use would you try to open the file for writing, so is the closest you're going to get to a reliable solution.

To test the solutions given here, with the various combinations of user, group and permissions, you could do:

```perl
perl -e '
  for $u (1,2) {
    for $g (1,2,3) {
      $d1="u${u}g$g"; mkdir$d1;
      for $m (0..511) {
        $d2=$d1.sprintf"/%03o",$m; mkdir $d2; chown $u, $g, $d2; chmod $m,$d2;
        for $uu (1,2) {
          for $gg (1,2,3) {
            $d3="$d2/u${uu}g$gg"; mkdir $d3;
            for $mm (0..511) {
              $f=$d3.sprintf"/%03o",$mm;
              open F, ">","$f"; close F;
              chown $uu, $gg, $f; chmod $mm, $f
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }'
```

Varying user between 1 and 2 and group betweem 1, 2, and 3 and limiting ourselves to the lower 9 bits of the permissions as that's already 9458694 files created. That for directories and then again for files.

That creates all possible combinations of `u<x>g<y>/<mode1>/u<z>g<w>/<mode2>`. The user with uid 1 and gids 1 and 2 would have write access to `u2g1/010/u2g3/777` but not `u1g2/677/u1g1/777` for instance.

Now, all those solutions try to identify the paths of files that the user may open for writing, that's different from the paths where the user may be able to modify the content. To answer that more generic question, there are several things to take into account:

1. $user may not have write access to `/a/b/file` but if he owns `file` (and has search access to `/a/b`, and the file system is not read-only, and the file doesn't have the immutable flag, and he's got shell access to the system), then he would be able to change the permissions of the `file` and grant himself access.
2. Same thing if he owns `/a/b` but doesn't have search access to it.
3. $user may not have access to `/a/b/file` because he doesn't have search access to `/a` or `/a/b`, but that file may have a hard link at `/b/c/file` for instance, in which case he may be able to modify the content of `/a/b/file` by opening it via its `/b/c/file` path.
4. Same thing with *bind-mounts*. He may not have search access to `/a`, but `/a/b` may be *bind-mounted* in `/c`, so he could open `file` for writing via its `/c/file` other path.
5. He may not have write permissions to `/a/b/file`, but if he has write access to `/a/b` he can remove or rename `file` in there and replace it with his own version. He would change the content of the file at `/a/b/file` even if that would be a different file.
6. Same thing if he's got write access to `/a` (he could rename `/a/b` to `/a/c`, create a new `/a/b` directory and a new `file` in it.

To find the paths that `$user` would be able to modify. To address 1 or 2, we can't rely on the `access(2)` system call anymore. We could adjust our `find -perm` approach to assume search access to directories, or write access to files as soon as you're the owner:

```
groups=$(id -G "$user" | sed 's/ / -o -group /g'); IFS=" "
find / -type d \
  \( \
    -user "$user" -o \
    \( -group $groups \) \( -perm -g=x -o -prune \) -o \
    -perm -o=x -o -prune \
  \) ! -type d -o -type l -o \
    -user "$user" -print -o \
    \( -group $groups \) \( ! -perm -g=w -o -print \) -o \
    ! -perm -o=w -o -print
```

We could address 3 and 4, by recording the device and inode numbers or all the files $user has write permission to and report all the file paths that have those dev+inode numbers. This time, we can use the more reliable  `access(2)`-based approaches:

Something like:

```
find / ! -type l -print0 |
  sudo -u "$user" perl -Mfiletest=access -0lne 'print 0+-w,$_' |
  perl -l -0ne '
    ($w,$p) = /(.)(.*)/;
    ($dev,$ino) = stat$p or next;
    $writable{"$dev,$ino"} = 1 if $w;
    push @{$p{"$dev,$ino"}}, $p;
    END {
      for $i (keys %writable) {
        for $p (@{$p{$i}}) {
          print $p;
        }
      }
    }'
```

5 and 6 are at first glance complicated by the `t` bit of the permissions. When applied on directories, that's the *restricted deletion* bit which prevents users (others than the owner of the directory) from removing or renaming the files they don't own (even though they have write access to the directory).

For instance, if we go back to our earlier example, if you have write access to `/a`, then you should be able to rename `/a/b` to `/a/c`, and then recreate a `/a/b` directory and a new `file` in there. But if the `t` bit is set on `/a` and you don't own `/a`, then you can only do it if you own `/a/b`. That gives:

- If you own a directory, as per 1, you can grant yourself write access, and the t bit doesn't apply (and you could remove it anyway), so you can delete/rename/recreate any file or dirs in there, so all file paths under there are yours to rewrite with any content.
- If you don't own it but have write access, then:

  - Either the `t` bit is not set, and you're in the same case as above (all file paths are yours).
  - or it's set and then you can't modify the files you don't own or don't have write access to, so for our purpose of finding the file paths you can modify, that's the same as not having write permission at all.

So we can address all of 1, 2, 5 and 6 with:

```
find / -type d \
  \( \
    -user "$user" -prune -exec find {} + -o \
    \( -group $groups \) \( -perm -g=x -o -prune \) -o \
    -perm -o=x -o -prune \
  \) ! -type d -o -type l -o \
    -user "$user" \( -type d -o -print \) -o \
    \( -group $groups \) \( ! -perm -g=w -o \
       -type d ! -perm -1000 -exec find {} + -o -print \) -o \
    ! -perm -o=w -o \
    -type d ! -perm -1000 -exec find {} + -o \
    -print
```

That and the solution for 3 and 4 are independent, you can merge their output to get a complete list:

```
{
  find / ! -type l -print0 |
    sudo -u "$user" perl -Mfiletest=access -0lne 'print 0+-w,$_' |
    perl -0lne '
      ($w,$p) = /(.)(.*)/;
      ($dev,$ino) = stat$p or next;
      $writable{"$dev,$ino"} = 1 if $w;
      push @{$p{"$dev,$ino"}}, $p;
      END {
        for $i (keys %writable) {
          for $p (@{$p{$i}}) {
            print $p;
          }
        }
      }'
  find / -type d \
    \( \
      -user "$user" -prune -exec sh -c 'exec find "$@" -print0' sh {} + -o \
      \( -group $groups \) \( -perm -g=x -o -prune \) -o \
      -perm -o=x -o -prune \
    \) ! -type d -o -type l -o \
      -user "$user" \( -type d -o -print0 \) -o \
      \( -group $groups \) \( ! -perm -g=w -o \
         -type d ! -perm -1000 -exec sh -c 'exec find "$@" -print0' sh {} + -o -print0 \) -o \
      ! -perm -o=w -o \
      -type d ! -perm -1000 -exec sh -c 'exec find "$@" -print0' sh {} + -o \
      -print0
} | perl -l -0ne 'print unless $seen{$_}++'
```

As should be clear if you've read everything thus far, part of it at least only deals with permissions and ownership, not the other features that may grant or restrict write access (read-only FS, ACLs, immutable flag, other security features...). And as we process it in several stages, some of that information may be wrong if the files/directories are being created/deleted/renamed or their permissions/ownership modified while that script is running, like on a busy file server with millions of files.

### Portability notes

All that code is standard (POSIX, Unix for `t` bit) except:

- `-print0` is a GNU extension now also supported by a few other implementations. With `find` implementations that lack support for it, you can use `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +` instead, and replace `-exec sh -c 'exec find "$@" -print0' sh {} +` with `-exec sh -c 'exec find "$@" -exec printf "%s\0" {\} +' sh {} +`.
- `perl` is not a POSIX-specified command but is widely available. You need `perl-5.6.0` or above for `-Mfiletest=access`.
- `zsh` is not a POSIX-specified command. That `zsh` code above should work with zsh-3 (1995) and above.
- `sudo` is not a POSIX-specified command. The code should work with any version as long as the system configuration allows running `perl` as the given user.

Comment: What is a _search_ access ? I have never heard of it in the traditional permissions : read, write, execute.

Comment: @bela83, _execute_ permission on a directory (you don't execute directories) translates to _search_. That's the ability to access files in it. You can list a directory's content if you have read permission, but you can't do anything with the files in it unless you also have search (`x` bit) permission on the directory. You can also have search permissions but not _read_, meaning files in there are hidden to you, but if you know their name, you can access them. A typical example is the php session file directory (something like /var/lib/php).

Answer (score 2):

You can combine options with the `find` command, so it will find out the files with specified mode and owner. For instance:

```
$ find / \( -group staff -o -group users \) -and -perm -g+w
```

The above command will list all entries which belong to the group "staff" or "users" and have write permission for that group.

You should also check for entries which are owned by your user, and files wich are world writable, so:

```
$ find / \( -user yourusername -or \
             \(  \( -group staff -o -group users \) -and -perm -g+w \
             \) -or \
            -perm -o+w \
         \)
```

However, this command won't match entries with extended ACL. So you may `su` then find out all writable entries:

```
# su - yourusername
$ find / -writable
```

Comment: That would say that a file with `r-xrwxrwx yourusername:anygroup` or `r-xr-xrwx anyone:staff` is writeable.

Comment: It would also report as writeable files that are in directories `yourusername` doesn't have access to.

Answer (score 1):

The approach depends upon what you are really testing.

1. Do you want to *ensure* write access is possible?
2. Do you want to *ensure* lack of write access?

This is because there are so many ways to arrive at 2) and Stéphane's answer covers these well (immutable is one to remember), and recall that there are physical means as well, such as unmounting the drive or making it read-only at a hardware level (floppy tabs). I am guessing your thousands of files are in differing directories and you are wanting a report or you are checking against a master list. (Another abuse of Puppet just waiting to happen).

You likely want Stéphane's perl tree-traversal and to "join" the output with a list if required (su will also catch missing execute on parent directories?). If surrogacy is a performance issue are you doing this for a "large number" of users ? Or is it an online query ? If this is a permanent ongoing requirement it may be time to consider a third party product.

Answer (score 0):

You can do...

```
find / ! -type d -exec tee -a {} + </dev/null
```

...for a list of all files to which the user *cannot* write as written to stderr in the form...

```
"tee: cannot access %s\n", <pathname>"
```

...or similar.

See the comments below for notes on the issues this approach might have, and the explanation below for why it might work. More sanely, though, you should probably *only* [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) regular files like:

```
find / -type f -exec tee -a {} + </dev/null
```

In short, `tee` will print errors when it attempts to [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html) a file with either of the two flags...

> O_WRONLY
>
> > Open for writing only.
>
> O_RDWR
>
> > Open for reading and writing. The result is undefined if this flag is applied to a FIFO.

...and encounters...

> [EACCES]
>
> > Search permission is denied on a component of the path prefix, or the file exists and the permissions specified by oflag are denied, or the file does not exist and write permission is denied for the parent directory of the file to be created, or O_TRUNC is specified and write permission is denied.

...as specified [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//utilities/tee.html):

> The `tee` utility shall copy standard input to standard output, making a copy in zero or more files. The tee utility shall not buffer output.
>
> If the `-a` option is not specified, output files shall be written (see [File Read, Write, and Creation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_01_01_04))...
>
> ...POSIX.1-2008 requires functionality equivalent to using ***O_APPEND***...

Because it has to check the same way [`test -w`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) does...

> `-w`  *pathname*
>
> > True if *pathname* resolves to an existing directory entry for a file for which permission to write to the file will be granted, as defined in [File Read, Write, and Creation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_01_01_04). False if *pathname* cannot be resolved, or if *pathname* resolves to an existing directory entry for a file for which permission to write to the file will not be granted.

They both check for ***EACCESS***.

Comment: You're likely to run into a limit of number of concurrently open files with that approach (unless the number of files is low). Beware of side effects with devices and named pipes. You'll get a different error message for sockets.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - All tue - I think it might be also true that `tee` will hang unless explicitly interrupted once per run. It was the closest thing I could think of to `[ -w`... though - it's effects should be close in that it guarantees the user can OAPPEND the file. Much easier than either option would be `pax` with `-o` format options and/or `-t` for checking against `EACCESS` - but every time I suggest `pax` people seem to shrug it off. And, anyway, the only `pax` I've found that meets the std there is AST's - in which case you might as well use their `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to use `find`'s `writable` predicate?

```
find /some/path -writable
```

From the man page

> -writable
> Matches files which  are  writable.   This  takes  into  account
> access  control  lists and other permissions artefacts which the
> -perm test ignores.  This test makes use of the access(2) system
> call,  and  so can be fooled by NFS servers which do UID mapping
> (or root-squashing), since many systems implement  access(2)  in
> the  client's  kernel  and so cannot make use of the UID mapping
> information held on the server.